# How to calculate the standard deviation for each row?

Tags: awk, math

I have file of 61 columns; I would like to calculate the standard deviation (SD) for each row with ignoring the 1st column and print the results against the 1st column, please note that the number of columns is not the same for each row and also some rows have only values for the first column which is not including in calculating the SD

```
input file
0.0  4  6  5  1  2  9  4  5  1  ..... 
0.5  3  1  
1.0  3  7  8  2  
1.5  3  3  3  4  6  4  5   
2.0  
2.5  6  7  6  9
```

Comment: Off-topic, big time.

Comment: @Cbhihe Sounds like a homework question to me.

Comment: @Cbhihe No, not really. It's a bit more involved than our average data processing question but not wildly off-topic. [It may be a duplicate](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=standard%20deviation): Moshen, do check our existing questions.

Comment: @Gilles: My interpretation (may be off) if that this has litterally _nothing_ to do with \*nix. Sure, it can be answered here, as it is... so perhaps in that sense is it not *really* off-topic. However it remains a sideline topic just holding by the one thread, we call ... `awk`. Maybe not fully "off-topic" but definitely on the wrong side of "borderline" (at best) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is hardly a linux question

```
awk 'NF>1{ s=0;s2=0;c=NF-1 ;
           for (i=2; i<=NF;i++) { s+=$i ; s2+=$i*$i;}
           # compute sd from c,s and s2
           printf "%f\n",sqrt((s2/c)-(s/c)^2) ;}'
```

Comment: please check it again it gives  syntax error

Comment: ok now, it is working however,  I would like to print the results (SD) against the 1st column

Comment: @Cbhihe My edit corrected the syntax errors.

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy Are you trying to get us to do your homework for you? The answer is already 99% of what you asked for; surely you can go the final 1% on your own. Try reading the `awk(1)` man page as suggested, or perhaps read [Apple’s tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Howawk-ward/Howawk-ward.html).

Comment: Hope you credit @Archemar when you submit your homework ;-)

Comment: you are right; I have already done

Comment: @steve: Full credits to Archemar **and** Lawrence Velázquez...